# TypeScript 2.0 and VS 2017 Build Tools no longer deploy js files

Tags: typescript, deployment, msdeploy, visual-studio-2017

I recently upgraded from VS 2015 Update 3 to VS 2017 which upgraded my solution from TypeScript 1.8 to TypeScript 2.1.

I changed `TypeScriptToolsVersion` in my `.csproj` file from `1.8` to `2.1` like so:

[image]

Here is the full PropertyGroup:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>9.0.30729</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{redacted}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{redacted};{redacted}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>WebApplication</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>WebApplication</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileUpgradeFlags>
    </FileUpgradeFlags>
    <OldToolsVersion>4.0</OldToolsVersion>
    <UpgradeBackupLocation />
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
    <UseIISExpress>false</UseIISExpress>
    <WcfConfigValidationEnabled>True</WcfConfigValidationEnabled>
    <IISExpressSSLPort /><IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>disabled</IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>
    <IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>enabled</IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>
    <IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode>false</IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode>
    <UseGlobalApplicationHostFile />
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>2.1</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Prior to the upgrade, the deployment would copy the `.js` and `.map.js` files that were associated with a `.ts` file. (note these `.js` files were not "included" in the solution.

After the upgrade, the deployment does not copy the associated `.js` or `.map.js` files.

Oddly enough, the `.js` files that had no associated TypeScript sources were copied successfully such as `jquery.js`. These files are "included" in the solution.

I can confirm the build does have the associated `.js` files as expected...its just the deployment step does not copy them.

I am using msdeploy for deployment like so:

```
WebApplication.deploy.cmd https://WEBSERVER01:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=test.example.com TheUser ThePassword
```

Why are these files not copying anymore and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be fixed in 15.2